# Is It possible to set .gif as ionic2 splash screens intead of .png?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen, ionic3

I have working on Ionic 2 project and want to set a .GIF image as splash screen .
If it is possible then please guide me how to set the same .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Splash screens are converted to platform specific resources, which is displayed while all the Ionic runtime is initializing. Both Android and iOS only supports static images for this.

You may be able to display something cool while performing asynchronous network requests. This has to be after the app is initialized, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the kind and helpfull  information , 
i havent rights to make upvote till 15 reputations  , i will do it after getting 15 reputations. thanks a lot .

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted instead of commenting with 'Thanks'. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sure i can do that  :D

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do directly, but there are some workarounds, for example using the SVG animation.

[image]

Check this tutorial from joshmorony.com:

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/

Hope it helps!